# ANDROID : can't get message from handler

Tags: android, handler, message

i've been waste 4 hours to search this answers but i still haven't found yet.
i tried to get message from handler, and the return data is json like this :

it will return data will be like this :

{"result": true,
    "trx_id": "2014222712220347248",
    "t_id": "this_is_my_t_id" }

i only can get all the value, but not per fields, i only want to get the t_id in this case.

anyone can help me?
thanks in advance

this is my code :

```
    Handler myHandler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean handleMessage(Message message) {
                        TextView textView = (TextView) someAPI.this
                                .findViewById(R.id.textviewResult);
                        textView.setText("RESULT : "
                                + message.getData().getString("result"));


                        return true;
                    }
                });
```

UPDATE :

solved with try like this :

```
 JSONObject jsonObj;
                        try {
                            jsonObj = new JSONObject(coba);
                            Log.d("DATA!", jsonObj.getString("t_id"));
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

thanks.

Comment: I think you can also convert `message` into `JSON` object and then get all the values from it. Try that, I think it'll work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

Via JSON object you can fetch the value of a specific string.

```
JsonObject jsonObj = new JsonObject(message);
jsonObj.getString("t_id");
```

Comment: i received this error The constructor JSONObject(Message) is undefined. any advice?

Comment: I want to know message is of which type

Comment: thanks its solved :) your answers is almost right. thanks in advance :)

Comment: If this answer helps you, please up the answer